# How to remove network-manager access from LightDM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, script, login, sudo

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04. I didn't like how LightDM gave access to network manager before anyone has actually logged in... So I added 'network-manager stop' to rc.local. It works just like how I want...

But I want it to start back up when an authenticated user actually logs in to the system. All the stuff I found by googling mostly suggest adding something to rc.local but that won't work for what I want to do because that script is run before LightDM shows up.

Is there a way to run a command as root when a user logs actually in?

Comment: have you tried launching it from `/etc/init/lightdm.conf`? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

Comment: Yeah I tried using hooks but they failed and made it so I couldn't log in... I tried this 'session-setup-script=service network-manager start'

Comment: I decided to go back to messing around with hooks and I finally got it to work... I'm going to post an answer to my question in a few.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the network manager from LightDM I did the following...

1) I added the following line to /etc/rc.local

sudo service network-manager stop

2) I created a script in /usr/bin named network-manager-start that runs the following command:

sudo service network-manager start

3) I created another script in /usr/bin named network-manager-stop that runs the following command:

sudo service network-manager stop

4) I added the following two lines to /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf:

session-setup-script=network-manager-start
session-cleanup-script=network-manager-stop

Comment: Not sure if the scripts really need to have sudo in them. Also not sure that I really need to keep the change to /etc/rc.local... but it works like this so I'm not touching it.

Comment: Also if anyone else ever reads this because they are trying to do the same thing.... Don't forget to run this on your scripts... sudo chmod a+x on  .... thats what messed me up the first time.